# Quickblox for not-in-list-contact chat

Tags: android, ios, audio, video, quickblox

We are tring to integrate `quickblox` in our Android and iOS app for video, audio and text chat. We see errors due to the fact that two partners are not already in each others contact list. Our app provide some kind of chat functions from operators to clients who are not in each other contact lists because of the nature of our services. Now we are stuck there.

Comment: You need to make your question more specific and add more relevant information to it.

Comment: Thanks sudomakeinstall2, which info you need?